# Google app engine how to upload config.py separately rather than as part of a blob

Tags: google-app-engine

Why cannot we upload the config.py as a separate entity rather than as a part of the blob?

Comment: ...what? What does a Python file have to do with entities and blobs?

Comment: config.py file resides in a google app engine project . once we upload the entire project as a blob we cannot separately upload an individual file like a configuration file(config.py).

Comment: I still don't understand. How are you "upload[ing] the entire project as a blob"? What are you actually doing?